# Use Foreach loop in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I process the `foreach` loop in MVC. In the bellow controller I am calling a method called `SendSimpleMessage()` which sends an email to its parameter input but on my controller I am unable to use `foreach` properly.

[image: screenshot]

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmailCampaignProcess(FormCollection collection)
        {
            //var userType = Request["userType"];
            //var emailContent = Request["emailContent"];
            //SendSimpleMessage();
            //ViewBag.Message = "Hello " + Request["userType"];


            var Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();


            foreach (Emails as Email) {

                SendSimpleMessage(Email);

            }

        }
```

Comment: foreach (email in Emails) { SendSimpleMessage(email); } you iterate trough Emails, not Email. Then for each "email" you do something.

Comment: Recommended reading https://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Questions in English go with a question mark, ?, and can receive an answer. Please ask an actual question, as that's what you filled out a box for.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, a `foreach` loop should look like

```
foreach (var currentEmail in Emails) { //where var can be your Class maybe Email
    SendSimpleMessage(currentEmail);
}
```

Generally a foreach looks like:

```
foreach(T objectName in YourCollection){
       //T is your class
       //objectName is the way you access the object within your loop
       //in references the list
       //YourCollection is IEnumerable<T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Defintion of ForEach Statement**

The for each statement is used to iterate through a collection. You can modify elements in a collection, but you cannot add or delete elements.The statements are executed for each element in the array or collection. After the iteration has been completed for all the elements in the collection, control is transferred to the statement that follows the for each block

**Syntax:**

```
   for each (type identifier in expression) 
  {  
       statements  
    }
```

**Parameters type**

The type of identifier.

**identifier**

The iteration variable that represents the collection element. When identifier is a Tracking Reference Operator, you can modify the element.

**expression**

An array expression or collection. The collection element must be such that the compiler can convert it to the identifier type.

**statements**

One or more statements to be executed.

**Simple Example:**

```
string[] countries = { "india", "US", "UK" };


        foreach (string value in countries )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
```

**In the same way your code will change like below:**

```
 [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult EmailCampaignProcess(FormCollection collection)
            {
                //var userType = Request["userType"];
                //var emailContent = Request["emailContent"];
                //SendSimpleMessage();
                //ViewBag.Message = "Hello " + Request["userType"];


                var Emails = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true)).Select(u => u.Email).ToArray();

 foreach (string SingleEmail in Emails) {

                    SendSimpleMessage(SingleEmail);

                }
         // Or if you are not sure about the outcome type you can use the var keyword like below

                foreach (var SingleEmail in Emails) {

                    SendSimpleMessage(SingleEmail);

                }

            }
```

Hope the above information was helpful